# How to shrinkwrap a image texture on a cloth and make the texture 3D (coming out of the cloth)

Tags: modeling, image, cloth-simulation

[image]

[image]

I want to have any image texture that is a design (png format) and shrinkwrap it to a cloth and add in the wool material that I can see in the image below. I am not able to recreate the 3D part where the design sticks out. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Hello, you could use a normal map to fake the 3D relief, have you tried that?

Comment: Hi @moonboots, can you let me know how to replicate that?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Here is the node setup for how you would 'fake' the effect. This doesn't affect any of the vertices of the object and only adds a slight bump look. This isn't a great way to do it as it only really looks passable from a front perspective. If you want to actually create a displacement on the model you would have to use a displacement setup like below:
[image]
To do this, you would first have to set your render engine to Cycles and either already have a lot of vertices on the model, or set the Cycles feature set to Experimental and use a subdivision surface modifier with adaptive subdivision like below:

[image]

If you use the displacement way of doing this then you also have to go to your material settings and change the displacement setting to either 'Displacement Only' or 'Displacement and Bump':
[image]